# Is it possible to run Tor in virtual machine with only 256 Megabyte of RAM?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I would like to know if it is feasible to run Tor in virtual machine with 256 MB of RAM.
If so, which flavor of linux minimal enough to run it?

Comment: From the tag I guess that you would like to run the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) in the VM. Am I right? --- I think that **256 MB of RAM is too low** for Firefox included in TBB. See http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/27.0/system-requirements/. --- You should also probably add additional information to the question: CPU architecture, virtualization solution you would like to use etc.

Comment: sorry myanswer may not be exact,I will be using virtualbox ,which ever is not resource hungry I am ok with it

Comment: This question really doesn't provide enough information to be useful. Are you wanting Linux to be the virtual OS or the host OS (or both)? What sort of hardware are you using? Does your chipset provide hardware virtualization (most CPUs do these days)? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any distribution which doesn't ship too much rubbish. Don't use a 64-bit OS, because that uses more memory.

Debian can easily run Tor on x86.

But if you wanted a GUI, you are going to have to be patient. Or use Windows XP (although 256M is still pushing it a bit).